# Solution to quadratic question of the form 0/0

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

What are the possible values of $x$ for the following equation:

$$\frac{x - 1}{1 - x} = \frac1x$$

This equation is equivalent to $$x^2 - 1 = 0$$

which factors to $1, -1$.

However, is $1$ the correct answer to the original form of equation? Given that if one substitutes $1$ in the given form of equation, the LHS becomes $\frac{0}{0}$. In case, $1$ is actually the correct answer, please explain what is the catch here.

Comment: To get from $x^2-1=0$ to $(x-1)/(1-x)=1/x$, you have to assume that $x\neq 1$, or you are dividing by zero.

Comment: It would have been simpler to note that if $x\ne 1$ then $\frac{x-1}{1-x}=-1$.

Comment: Just because you can go from one equation to another doesn't mean they're equivalent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is *not* equivalent to $x^2-1=0$.  You can multiply both sides by $x(1-x)$ and get $x^2-1=0$, but that is valid only if the denominator $1-x$ is not $0$, and the denominator is $0$ when $x=1$, so you have to check separately whether $x=1$ is a solution to the original equation $\dfrac{x-1}{1-x}=\dfrac 1 x$.  And it is not.  So the original equation is actually equivalent to this:
$$
x^2-1=0\text{ and } x\ne 1.
$$

Comment: More precisely, although not directly influencing the results, the original equation is equivalent to this: $$x^2-1=0\, \mathrm{and}\,x\ne1\,\mathrm{and}\,x\ne0.$$

Comment: @Ruslan : But $x^2-1=0$ already implies that $x\ne0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 8):

Note that the equation $\frac{x-1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{x}$ only makes sense for $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{0,1\right\}$, so $x=-1$ is the only root of the original equation.

Comment: You should add an answer to the question "where is the catch", meaning, where in OP's argumentation is the error.

Answer (score 7):

To write the first equation, there is an implicit condition in the moment you decide to write $\frac{x-1}{1-x}$ to avoid dividing by zero, which is $x\ne 1$. Thus, even though the equation you arrive at ($x^2-1=0$) has solutions $\pm 1$, the condition must be considered since you arrived at it from the first.

For that reason, the possible values of $x$ for the equation are all except $x=1$, and $x=0$ as well (because for the same reason regarding divisibility, on the right side $\frac{1}{x}$ can not be $x=0$).

Comment: @Quincunx then my English is wrong because I did not mean that, I agree with what you said. What I am stating is regarding the final equation, not the original expression, for the original expression are still $-1$ and $+1$.

Comment: @Quincunx just to clarify I have added some explanation, non English native speaker here...

Comment: Okay. I want to suggest that you mention that there is another value which $x$ cannot be: $0$.

Comment: @Quincunx true! I was too focused on explaining the left side, thanks for that.